How to change the background color for Jupyter Notebook runtime errors in Visual Studio Code?
I am using Visual Studio Code for Jupyter Notebooks in a dark theme and I cannot see the errors because of the default background colors. I have attached the screenshot where the error is highlighted yellow and totally Illegible

I am not sure which option to select from the workbench color customization settings. I tried some options listed with error but none were helpful:


The error is apart of the output container, thus changing notebook.outputContainerBackgroundColor changes the background of it as well:
{
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "[SkillAvid Pure Black]": {
       "notebook.outputContainerBackgroundColor": "#1f3ab3",
    }
  }
}

Here is an example:

